# search Instagram with multiple hashtags - API

Tags: api, instagram

i have read that it is not possible by Instagram API , but the example site hashtagpirate.com does it, and there is an app on iOS as well, so there must be a way

i am developing a website with PHP and Instagram API, and have a plan for an App later on, can anyone point me to documentation on Instagram API which supports multiple hashtags fetching , as current API documentation ( below example code) doesn't seem to fetch more than one tag at a time

```
<?php

require 'Instagram.php';

$instagram = new Instagram('id');

$tag = 'selfie';

$media = $instagram->getTagMedia($tag);

 echo "<ul id=\"photos\">";
  foreach ($media->data as $data) {
    echo "<li><img src=\"{$data->images->thumbnail->url}\"></li>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";

?>
```

i cant send more than one tag (selfie), and if i send two tags , the results are separate

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a separate search for each tag and then combine them yourself before presenting them to your users.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the construction of instagrams database, you aren`t able to search instagram for multiple hashtags directly. 
You have to use some third party sites like hashtagpirate.com or the free alternative [vanadium](https://vanadium-space.000webhostapp.com)